# ASP.NET: Server with Static IP, SMTP and WebRequest for Email and SMS not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, ip, webrequest

I have successfully tested both SMTP email as well as SMS(Using httpwebrequest) on my developer machine which uses normal IP address. But both SMTP mail and SMS are not working after I publish the files to client having server with static IP.

Note: The static server IP start with 14.141.XXX.XXX, it asks for username and password when a browser is opened.  I doubt whether my code also requires this authentication?

I have tried with and without the BindIPEndPointCallback method, But it didn't work.
My Code:

```
    public static IPEndPoint BindIPEndPointCallback(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
            {

                return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000);

            }



    //SMS Code:

public void SendSMS()
{
                    string url = @"www.someSMSurl.com/";
                    HttpWebRequest smsReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                    smsReq.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new BindIPEndPoint(BindIPEndPointCallback);
                    HttpWebResponse smsResp = (HttpWebResponse)smsReq.GetResponse();
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(smsResp.GetResponseStream());
                    string SMSRespoContent = sr.ReadToEnd();



}
```

After some time after I click send SMS, I get the following error:

Detailed:
Server Error in '/' Application.
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 198.211.43.82:80
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 198.211.43.82:80

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
public static IPEndPoint BindIPEndPointCallback(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint              remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
           {

         return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000);

          }



    //SMS Code:

  public void SendSMS()
    {

                    string url = @"www.somesmsurl.com/";
                      HttpWebRequest smsReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);          
                    smsReq.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new BindIPEndPoint(BindIPEndPointCallback);
                    HttpWebResponse smsResp = (HttpWebResponse)smsReq.GetResponse();
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(smsResp.GetResponseStream());
                    string SMSRespoContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

[SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 198.211.43.82:80]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +239
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP) +35
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) +224

[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +5408061
   MAM_Application.EmailProgress.SendSMS(String UN, String PW, String MN, String EvCode, String EvName, String NetworkUsername, String NetworkPassword, String NetworkDomain) +800
   MAM_Application.EmailProgress.btnSendSMS_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1281
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10`enter code here`
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565

Comment: You know that "www.somesmsurl.com/" is not a full URL correct? You're missing the protocol, ex: "http://www.somesmsurl.com/". Also, there's no need to use a string literal `@""` since it doesn't contain any special characters. A regular string will do fine.

Comment: Sorry, the above comment formatted incorrectly. The protocol should be included, ex: `http://`

Comment: I have included protocol. http://